# How to associate each Firebase user with their own recyclerView Data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app that display notes list in a recyclerView. I connected the app with firebase authentication and realtime database.

The Realtime Database JSON tree looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that I want "Notes" to be part of "Users" which is not the case, because when I login to my app, I found the same Notes in every user account. I want the notes to be displayed for a specific user when they create them.

Here is my code:

**SignupActivity.java**

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    EditText mName, mEmail,mPassword;
    Button mSignupBtn;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    View mViewHelper;

    GoogleSignInButton button;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.agree_terms)));

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        mSignupBtn = findViewById(R.id.create_btn);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);
        mViewHelper = findViewById(R.id.view_helper);
        button = findViewById(R.id.login_google_btn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mSignupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                final String name = mName.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    mName.setError("Name is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if(password.length() < 6) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Characters");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSignupBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                // register the user in firebase

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);

                            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("name", name);
                            user.put("email", email);
                            user.put("image", "default");
                            user.put("thumb_image", "default");

                            current_user_db.setValue(user);

                            documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created for "+ userID);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+ e.toString());
                                }
                            });


                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error !" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mViewHelper.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mSignupBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });

            }
        });


        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }

            }
        };

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("886475354465-j5suema9gt5mhi2fhli0un9vsn1olvaa.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {

                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Aut Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

**NotesAdapter.java**

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.MyHolder>
{

    List<Listdata> noteslist;
    private Context context;
    public  NotesAdapter(List<Listdata> noteslist,Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.noteslist=noteslist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);

        MyHolder myHolder=new MyHolder(view);
        return myHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int position) {
        Listdata data=noteslist.get(position);
        myHolder.title.setText(data.getTitle());
        myHolder.desc.setText(data.getDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteslist.size();
    }

    class  MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView title,desc;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Listdata listdata=noteslist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent i=new Intent(context, StreamActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",listdata.id);
                    i.putExtra("title",listdata.title);
                    i.putExtra("desc",listdata.desc);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }


    }
}
```

**AddNotesActivity.java**

```
public class AddNotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText title,desc;
    String titlesend,descsend;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_notes);

        title=findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc=findViewById(R.id.desc);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }

    public void AddNotes(View view) {
        titlesend=title.getText().toString();
        descsend=desc.getText().toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(titlesend) || TextUtils.isEmpty(descsend)){
            return;
        }
        AddNotes(titlesend,descsend);

    }

    private void AddNotes(String titlesend, String descsend)
    {

        String id=mDatabase.push().getKey();
        Listdata listdata = new Listdata(id,titlesend, descsend);
        mDatabase.child("Notes").child(id).setValue(listdata).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddNotesActivity.this, "Notes Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotesActivity.class));
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

**NotesActivity.java**

```
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Firebase instance variables
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

//HomeScreen variables
RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<Listdata> list =new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);


    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(NotesActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    // Notes Screen

    final NotesAdapter notesAdapter=new NotesAdapter(list,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("Notes");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Listdata listdata=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Listdata.class);
                list.add(listdata);

            }
            notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNotesActivity.class));
        }
    });

    // end NotesScreen


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser == null){
        sendToStart();
    }
}

private void sendToStart() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(NotesActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Please I need help on how should I modify my code to display the notes for a specific user when they create them. documentation links will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to change this line of code from **AddNotesActivity.java**

```
mDatabase.child("Notes").child(id)
```

to

```
mDatabase.child("Users").child(userID).child("Notes").child(id)
```

and don't forget to retrieve the data in **NotesActivity.java**

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Notes");
```